# Jython bring in java module Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jython

I'm a beginner in Jython and Java and I'm a little confused as to how to bring in my java class in Eclipse. Basically trying to replicate the beach part from this jython documentation.
http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html

So I have the same code as from the documentation, I believe my issue is related to the classpath, and I'm not sure what that means. Does that mean I need to build my .jar file and it has to be in the same directory as my jython code?

I get an error of unresolved import for "import Beach".

Java

```
package jython_test;

public class Beach {

private String name;
private String city;


public Beach(String name, String city){
    this.name = name;
    this.city = city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

Jython

```
import Beach

beach = Beach("Cocoa Beach","Cocoa Beach")
beach.getName()
beach.getCity()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would make a .jar file and copy/move it to your Projectfile in eclipse.

In eclipse you right-click on your Project and choose 'Properties'.
Then choose PyDev - PYTHONPATH and click on 'Add jar'.
After that you should be able to import stuff from your jarfile to your project.

That's the way I do in my projects (I'm also new to Jython =/ ).

Greets,

zonk